# Is it possible to get the raw param string in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

Given the following url:

```
http://foo.com?bar=1&wee=2
```

What is the quickest way to get the raw param part of the url from an action?

i.e.

```
?bar=1&wee=2
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sure, just use request.query_string from within your controller